# Box API returned Error : : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, box-api

i got the auth token using my api key den while trying to access user content i get this error

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Here is my c# code

```
string url = "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0 \\ -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"` is an argument of the example cURL command, not part of the API URL.  It indicates an HTTP Header.  You'll need to add that header to your `request` object.

Try this:

```
string url = "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN");
```

Alternatively, you could try the [Box C# SDK](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2), which will take care of all that for you.

Comment: ok thnks for dat.I had one more doubt.In order to create a shared link i need one more parameter...-d '{"shared_link": {"access": "Open"}}' \.How should i add this to the request

Comment: I can't post the code in a comment, but [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256136/setting-a-webrequests-body-data) should point you in the right direction.