# Converting batch file to powershell with special characters in path

Tags: batch-file, powershell-2.0, command-line-arguments

I'm having a hard time to write a simple batch file as powershell script.

Consider this folder structure. Note the directory with the cool `[1]` in it...
[image]

[**exiftool.exe**](https://exiftool.org/)
Is a command utility to (for example) extract pictures from embedded MP3 tags.
I [uploaded its help](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f723b55c5038f28de8f3) if you need more info.

**oldscript.cmd**
`exiftool -picture -b input.mp3 > output.jpg`
This line is the one to write in powershell. I found the syntax in a [forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php/topic,3856.msg17838.html) from the author

- `-picture` stands for the tag to extract and `-b` stands for binary mode
- `input.mp3` is my test mp3 which can contain special characters in its path like [ and ]
- `> output.jpg` defines the name and saves the resulting image in the same folder

**newscript.ps1**
My best current non-working code is:

```
$ownpath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$exe = $ownpath + '\exiftool.exe'
$input = $ownpath + '\input.mp3'
$outimg = $ownpath + '\output.jpg'    

& $exe -picture -binary $input| Set-Content -literalPath $outimg -encoding UTF8
```

I found `Set-Content` which is able to handle special characters in pathes through "-literalpath". But I'm still not able to convert the batch to a Powershell script because
Set-Content (and Out-File method too) seems work different compared to old batch piping (">"). The resulting image is not viewable regardless which encoding I use. The [help file from above](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f723b55c5038f28de8f3) says that exiftool is using UTF8 encoding.

Of course I tried other [available encodings](http://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html), but all of them failed to produce a viewable image. I'm stuck at this point. So my initial question still stands partly "How do I convert this batch file to powershell".

**So why is it working when using the old batch command?**

For example: create a folder "D:folder" and place this [MP3 file with a cover image](http://ge.tt/4PUs8hY/v/1) in it.
Download [exiftool.exe](https://exiftool.org/) from above and place it there too.

The old batch command will work and give you a viewable image

```
D:\folder\exiftool -picture -binary D:\folder\input.mp3 > D:\folder\output.jpg
```

The new Powershell V2 script with the same syntax will fail. Why?

```
& D:\folder\exiftool.exe -picture -binary D:\folder\input.mp3 > D:\folder\output.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, though I've not tested it 'cause I've not an mp3 with embedded images:

```
$file = & "D:\folder\exiftool.exe" -picture -binary "D:\folder\input.mp3"

[io.file]::WriteAllBytes('D:\folder\input[1].jpg',$file)
```

Edit:

using this line from a powershell console return a readable image:

```
 cmd.exe /c "D:\folder\exiftool.exe -picture -binary `"D:\folder\input.mp3`" > image.jpg"
```

You can use special characters in path and in file name as:

```
 $exe = "c:\ps\exiftool.exe"
 $mp3 = "c:\ps\a[1]\input.mp3" 
 $jpg = " c:\ps\a[1]\image[1].jpg"

 cmd.exe /c "$exe -picture -binary $mp3 > $jpg"
```

with spaces inside path:

```
 $exe = "c:\ps\exiftool.exe"
 $mp3 = "`"c:\ps\a [1]\input.mp3`"" 
 $jpg = "`"c:\ps\a [1]\image [1].jpg`""

 cmd.exe /c "$exe -picture -binary $mp3 > $jpg"
```

Comment: Tested it. Gives error `Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "System.Object[]", for "WriteAllBytes" to type "System.Byte[]": "Cannot convert value " ╪ α JFIF █ ä " to type "System.Byte". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""` Here is an [example MP3](http://ge.tt/4PUs8hY/v/1) if you need it to test.

Comment: @nixda Thanks for mp3 example. I've found an alternative, added code in my answer.

Comment: Close one. Insert a space in "a[1]" » "a [1]" and it won't work. I guess the variables need to be enclosed with double quotes. But how?

Comment: This works with a slight modification. See my answer. If no one with a real Powershell V2 solution comes up, I will accept your answer in a few days. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
& $exe -picture -b $input | Out-File -LiteralPath $output
```

There is no need to complicate things by using Start-Process.  Because you compute the path to the exe and put that result in a string, you only need use the call operator `&` to invoke the command named by the string that follows it.

Comment: Have you tested that? Because Out-File [doesn't understand -LiteralPath](http://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html). Even if I delete the special character `[1]`, the output file is created but not viewable. The tool works if called from a batch, but not from PS.

Comment: It works on PowerShell 3.0.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Comment: Please see my edit. I went one step further with Set-Content which has literalpath in V2 too. But the resulting file is somehow handled different compared to old windows batch and piping with ">"

Comment: IIRC there were a number of LiteralPath issues fixed by v3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around. It seems you can't avoid good old cmd.exe completely.
Thanks should go @ C.B.

```
$ownpath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$exe = $ownpath + '\exiftool.exe'
$input = $ownpath + '\input.mp3'
$output = $ownpath + '\output.jpg'

cmd.exe /c " `"$exe`" -picture -binary `"$input`" > `"$output`" "
```

[image]

**Note:**

- This way all pathes can contain special characters like [ and ] or spaces
- That extra space in `` " `"$exe `` is important.  It won't work without it.

The normal Powershell way with `set-content`, `Out-File` (">" is an alias) and `[io.file]::WriteAllBytes` all don't work with the exiftool.exe utility. For me its a miracle.