# Google Image Search using local image using python code

Tags: python, google-image-search

I did lots of search for Google Image Search using local image but not found any accurate answer. like what are the parameter we have to pass when upload a photo to google server. so any one know how i can use Google Image search for searching local image stored in my harddisk but using python programming. tell me if any Library or API available. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this api http://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of this question:

[Google Search by Image API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api)

---

The Google Image API is deprecated but as the answerer points out, there are alternatives like [tinyeye](http://www.tineye.com/).

Comment: hey @halflings i am looking for open source and free libs. is there any ?? and Google API doesnot provide local image search which is archieved by alternative ways so first alteast read above description...

Comment: You didn't say you were looking for **open-source** and **free of charge** APIs. And how would use Similar Image search if the Google Image API doesn't allow it? That's why I told you the API is deprecated.

Comment: this is open source just need to understand the package data .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634321/script-to-use-google-image-search-with-local-image-as-input