# Google image search by URL, unable to crawl the page

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, google-image-search

I am trying to use Google image search by **url** for research purposes. That was after I gave up searching by the actual image since I can't really get it to work.

**What is done so far**

Using PHP, I can issue an HTTP request to https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo117.png

If you copy that URL into your browser, you see the results (seems some automatic redirects take place here).

However, if you try to manually request the URL, through PHP for example, or through http://web-sniffer.net/?url=images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo117.png you get an HTTP 302 error that says that the page has been moved to some other URL.

I extracted that URL, tried it out on the browser and again it works. But again if you try this URL manually you get another HTTP 302 error, which finally takes you to Google's homepage.

I've seen questions like: [Script to use Google Image Search with local image as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634321/script-to-use-google-image-search-with-local-image-as-input) which seem to have been able to do it, but the asker didn't run into the same problem I did

Comment: You may find [this blog post](http://skyzerblogger.blogspot.be/2013/01/google-reverse-image-search-scraping.html) useful. The thing is, though, that there is no official reverse image search API, and that's deliberate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Google is performing a redirection based on the User-Agent in your request. So if you include a real User-Agent - something copied from a real web browser - the request should work correctly.

Here is some example php code that works for me:

```
$location = 'http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo117.png';

do {
  $ch = curl_init($location);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);

  $data = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$data);
  list($headers, $data) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
  $headers = explode("\n",$headers);

  $location = null;
  foreach ($headers as $header)
    if (stripos($header, 'Location:', 0) === 0)
      $location = trim(substr($header,9));

} while ($http_code == 302 && $location != null);

echo $data;
```

Comment: It's not just the user agent, but the loop that goes on requesting as long as there's a 302 error. As well as `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`, which worked on my online server. Another command `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` can get it to work on my localhost but for some reason this command, unlike yours, doesn't work on my server. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had the 302 part under control which is why I didn't mention it. And from what I understand, the FOLLOWLOCATION option is disabled when in safemode. That's probably why you can't use it on your live server.