# matlab: image search image in google

Tags: image, matlab

I am using matlab to create mosaic image.
To do this, I would like to use the Google image search instead of self-create my own image database.
The procedure will be:
1.get a image and divided it into small box.
2. for each box, using image search image to get a similar image and download to matlab 
3.combine every downloaded image to from the mosaic image.

I have try to search the internet by most of the result are only "words to image", instead of "image to  image",
will there be any example or other keys word for me to complete the step 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has the functionality to search for similar looking images. Just visit google.com and switch over to image search on the top. Then in the search bar, there is a little camera icon on the right. When you open this you can either choose a URL or directly upload an image you want to search for.

So what you firstly could do, would be to export the current box (e.g. as a jpg). Then, and this is where it may get tricky, code a script (maybe not in matlab but rather in some other scripting language, e.g. python) which uploads the current box image to the google image search and searches for appropriate pictures. I think you may be also able to use google custom search APIs - however I'm not familiar with it. You could then just call that script via matlab, which should be not a problem.

And downloading and fitting back together should not be that hard once you have accomplished the uploading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I get some idea. I have find some more related question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634321/script-to-use-google-image-search-with-local-image-as-input ,but i don't understand the VB script, but seem using the url can do reverse image search,isn't it? Or it is better that upload the image to image server like imgur  and get the direct link back for generating the image search url?

Comment: I think it may be easier to use the imgur way. They even provide a full API for uploading and extracting infos: https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image