# How to upload local file to google reverse image search via URL?

Tags: c#, url, google-image-search

I try to automate the upload of a local image file to google reverse image search. To be clear, I only want to do the upload. (Open default browser -> open google reverse image search -> upload local file -> end). I don't want to analyse the results of the search in any way.

After doing some research I found a simple solution for an online image by appending the image URL at the end of this:

`https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=`

That currently works like a charm. But is there a similar easy way for a local file upload? Without any API or encoding?

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding why you wouldn't upload the images directly to the google reverse. Are these uploads meant to be inplemented in your own program?

Comment: I want to reduce the time for the user to do the upload precedure. This may seem a bit unnecessary if you look at the time for a single search you are doing once in a while. But we need it quite often and that time summs up and the precedure can be quit annoying after some time.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that my goal is to do that as an one button operation out of a bigger program I wrote, handling mostly images. Only for bringing it in a bigger context where it will be used...

Comment: I don't see how or why you'd want to not use an API to handle this. It would be rather helpful if you showed how you are currently processing the images, since it is quite unclear what you are actually referring to

Comment: @Roe I have looked into API solutions and they are either deprecated and, as far as I know, all charge money after an amount of searches or am I wrong? [Google Search by Image API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api?rq=2) I am looking more in this direction: [Script to use Google Image Search with local image as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634321/script-to-use-google-image-search-with-local-image-as-input?rq=2) But to be honest, I have not the knowledge at the moment to make that work. So I hoped for a simpler solution by now.

Comment: have you looked into this https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview up to x amount of request a day should be free