# C# HttpWebRequest.Write does not send content

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Trying to send a web request with some body content. The important part is that I need some data in the body of the post request. My understanding of how to do this is to open a WebRequestStream, and then write the bytes to it, then to close it. This is supposed to be simple. Here is my code:

```
        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:50203/api/Values");//

        request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] requestBody = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("grant_type=client_credentials"));
            Stream requestBodyStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestBodyStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
            requestBodyStream.Flush();
            requestBodyStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            myString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But the RequestBodyStream.Write method is not sending anything in the body. I know this because I'm running the server side program at the other end.

I also tried to do this with a StreamWriter instead of using a byte stream, and I get the same result. No matter how I do it, there is no content in the body.

My understanding is that closing the stream is what sends the actual data. I also tried adding a Flush() method to the stream.

Why is this method not producing any body?

Comment: Your endpoint looks like asp.net Web API. Is that controller route a GET or  is it a POST endpoint?

Comment: @Crowcoder If it wasn't a POST endpoint, he would have get an exception in the client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a WebRequest's body data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256136/setting-a-webrequests-body-data)

Comment: @yonisha, good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'ContentType' and 'ContentLength' headers to the request instance:

```
request.ContentType = "application/json"; // Or whatever you want
request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
```