# Can I send variables in HttpWebRequest with a POST method

Tags: c#, post, get, httpwebrequest

I am a PHP developer doing a C# project

I have a C# winform project where the end user login to the software.

The login goes through a `HttpWebRequest`

```
            var user = txtuser.Text;
            var pass = txtpass.Text;
 

            var url = "https://www.example.com/directory/directory.php?";
            var var = "user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;
            var URL = url + var;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.  
            var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Display the content.  
            if (responseFromServer.Contains("Access") == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(4000);
                IsLoginTrue = true;
```

The connection is secured, but I am concerned about security because GET request are logged in plain text web logs.

Can I do an `HttpWebRequest` with a POST method?

Comment: That's a perfectly common scenario (sending data in a post request), so yes you can do it. Do you want to try this question again to be a bit more precise about the problem you're seeing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/12473121 Method C is what you are looking for

Comment: I think your problem will be solved by looking here:
[Setting a WebRequest's body data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256187/6300534)

Comment: Logging is up to the server to worry about, not the client. `HttpWebRequest` is basically deprecated, consider moving to `HttpClient`